# How do you convert AAC_ADTS files to WAV files in Kotlin for Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, wav, aac, adts

I have a few files from `MediaRecorder()` that I want to convert into WAV files (or preferably into CSV files), but I can't find any library on github that can convert between the two for Kotlin. WAV is also not a supported type of Audio file for Android Studio, so I don't know what to do.

Everything online just leads me to a online web converter, but I need the app to do this on its own without using the web. How do I do this?